# Windows renamed my network interfaces

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, network-adapter

I have a laptop with an ethernet and a Wifi connection. The names of these interfaces were "ethernet connection" and
"Wifi connection". Suddenly i realized that these names have changed to
"Ethernet connection 2" and "Wifi connection 2" correspondingly. I tried
to remove "2" from both but i am getting
an error message that an interface with
this name exists without showing other
interfaces listed.
My problem is that i want to remove the "2".
I would appreciate for your help.

My OS is windows 10 and my computer is an dell 2 years old model.

Comment: What is the issue?   Is something not working?  Otherwise I do not think this is anything to be concerned about.

Comment: I want to remove the "2".

Comment: Windows numbers adapters and if something changed / updated then the number changes.

Comment: I can not remove "2" but i can not.

Comment: No - built into the way Windows does adapters. It needs to keep track of adapters.

Comment: Ok but i have only 2 adapters. One wifi and one ethernet. Fistly the "2" wan to there and now it is with out any action of my site. I want this  "2" to get gone.

Comment: Open the Windows device manager, enable `Show hidden devices` and delete the two grayed-out network interfaces. Then the names should be free again. I assume you have installed some driver update for a system component that caused the network devices to be found again.

Comment: Windows has been doing this for a decade at least. Glance at it the wrong way & it re-enumerates the connections. It will even do this when running in VM with no physical ports to enumerate.  Learn to live with it, it doesn't actually hurt anything.

Comment: There was nothing renamed. How did find your existing devices? GUI? Shell? Please post a screen shot! Robert is most likely right in one form or another.